# Problem with Kohana detect_uri() when mod_rewrite enabled

Tags: php, request, kohana-3

I am having problem in detecting current uri when the requested controller is index. (my `index_file` file name is index.php). It seems the problem is in detect_uri() function since it checks `PATH_INFO` before `REQUEST_URI`. when my url is http://localhost/myapp/index/ $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'] returns `/` and when it's http://localhost/myapp/index/ index/ it returns `/index` . For all other controllers requests it returns empty and the system works fine. I am using Ubuntu 10.10. I think  when mod_rewrite is enabled in Debian system, `$_SERVER['PATH_INFO']` does not returns the expected value. someone please explain.

Thanks

Comment: What do you want it to return?

Comment: I expect it to return /index for the url http://localhost/myapp/index/

Answer (score 0):

Related to `mod_negotiation` and being able to access `/index.php` as `/index` (without the extension).

**Solution1:**

```
a2dismod negotiation
service apache2 restart
```

**Solution2:**

```
patch kohana/system/libraries/Router.php
```

http://pastebin.com/7EtGGiaG